# How to find Keys from a php application project source code

Tags: php, postgresql, nette, adminer

I am trying to start a php website and its database is missing currently i am stuck t this error can anyone help me what it is if it is keys how to find .[image: error currently i am facing]

Please suggest me how to get keys and database details from php files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to install a pre-built application on an Apache webserver. One would normally consult the documentation for setting up the application to find where database passwords are kept. From the error message displayed, it looks like connecting to the database is not the issue as it is complaining about a specific column. It may be a bug in the application. You could maybe try downloading the most recent version of the application if the one you have is not the most recent. Other than that, you may need to contact the developer and report the bug. De-bugging it yourself could be very time-consuming. You could try a different application in that case, maybe.

Comment: why it is not reading that column smtp_port which i created in the database

Comment: If you added columnt and you still see error, you probably didn't deleted app cache.